# FileNotFoundException taking too long to throw, is there a way to shorten the timeout?

Tags: c#, exception

I have some code which loads an image like this:

```
 using (var sourceImage = Image.FromFile(fullImagePath))
 {
    return new Bitmap(sourceImage);
 }
```

Occasionally the image will be misnamed or not be where expected and a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is correctly thrown.  However, it often takes about 1 second for this exception to be thrown.  When my code is grabbing a few hundred images and a several of them are missing then this adds a significant chunk of time to the process.

**Is there a way to speed up the exception if one needs to be thrown?**

The only alternative I can think of is to check to see if the image exists first, but that adds a few dozen milliseconds to every single image fetch which is not exactly a good solution either.

**Clarification**: An example of what `fullImagePath` contains is:

```
\\ImageSrv\secure\sites\2756\27074\760789\bthumb\1287.jpg
```

There may be a couple of hundred other images in the same directory.

**Conclusion**: Looks like checking for the files existence is the best way to go.

Comment: How about: If all images are in one directory, simply do a one-time fetch of all image file names via `Directory.GetFiles()` and then do only a string search (case-insensitive etc.) before loading. Kind of a "poor man's FileExists".

Comment: Do you absolutely need to throw an exception? This will always be slower than an explicit file exists check. If you're not re-throwing the exception, you could consider removing the try/catch.

Comment: @christofr Not _he_ is throwing, but the `Image.FromFile`.

Comment: @Uwe, unfortunately there are hundreds of thousands of files located in something like 600-700 hundred different directories.  Starting to look like I will have to check if the file exists first.  For most of my use cases this won't be too intrusive, but for some it can easily add a few seconds of processing time.

Comment: So this delay is *really* the file system having to dig through thousands of directory entries, not any delay in the exception getting thrown.  You can't fix that with software, you need a faster disk or a better structured set of directories.

Comment: @Hans, no... the code is grabbing one specific file from one specific location.  My comment about lots of files was in regards to Uwe's suggestion "If all the images are in one directory...".

Comment: @Hans, upon further review you are probably right... or at least _right enough_. There is some measurable delay from my system to the file server thanks to my VPN connection. One image typically takes ~380ms to get. If the exception is thrown the process takes ~900ms. It seems like the exception is still consuming too much time, but not as much as it first appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prevent the exception yourself. Check if file exists instead of letting Image.FromFile fail and go through the exception shenennigans
2. Keep the cache in your memory to remove necessity for additional hard drive calls
3. If situation requires, update cache using FileSystemWatcher

Comment: If you do this, make sure you still catch the exception. [Per Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a cache of File names which you periodically update via another thread. You could then check against that and know immediately if the file exists or not (bypassing the overhead of File.Exists)

Of course this won't work if the files in the directory are constantly being added/removed.